# Should L, TX, RX led light on while connected with laptop

Tags: power, stepper-motor

Dear Sir, 
               I need to know that should led light named as L, TX, RX should be on when we connect it with laptop?
Because when I connect it with laptop led light turns on for 1 or 2 second then turns off. That's why I am asking you this question.
                 Hoping for a favourable answer.
Your's faithful,
Nir Patel.

Comment: that would really depend on the device ... right now we have no idea what device you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

On Arduino Uno (and most basic Arduinos), the 'L' LED is operated by whatever code is on the Arduino. RX and TX flicker whenever the Arduino is sending data to the PC (TX) or is receiving data from the PC (RX).

If you have never re-programmed your Arduino, it is running whatever code was in it when it was shipped to you. It sounds like your Arduino has a bootloader but no code yet. The bootloader listens for the PC to try upload a new program. While it is listening, it blinks the L LED.

If the PC tries to upload, you will see the RX and TX lights flicker as the two communicate, until the upload is finished. Then whatever program was uploaded will run, and *it* will control the LEDs.

If the PC doesn't try to upload a new program within a few seconds (how long depends on which bootloader version is in the Arduino), the bootloader will start whatever program is already in the Arduino. Again, that program will then control the LEDs.